# Is it possible to have MKMap as background layer and UIButton/UTextField and front layer

Tags: ios

I'm having a view with MKmap and  UIButton/UTextField under it.

I thought it would be nice if I could bring the UIButton/UTextField "in front" of the map, so that map would look like a background.

any clue how could I do that? I'm new to iOS development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view controller that contains the map and the button, do this:

```
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myButton];

 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myTextField];
```